# useParams() unable to fetch path dynamically react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My code is unable to render the elements of the nested route component present in my QuoteDetail code block while I'm using the dynamic path value

```
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import AllQuotes from './pages/AllQuotes';
import QuoteDetail from './pages/QuoteDetail';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='/quotes' />} />
        <Route path='/quotes' element={<AllQuotes />} />
        <Route path='/quotes/*' element={<QuoteDetail />} />
        <Route path='/quotes/:quoteId' element={<QuoteDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my Quote details code

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Comments from "../components/comments/Comments";

const QuoteDetail = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  console.log(params.quoteId);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Quote Detail Page</h1>
      <p>{params.quoteId}</p>
      <Routes>
        <Route 
          path={`${params.quoteId}/comments`}
          element={<p>Hello</p>}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default QuoteDetail;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `QuoteDetail` is rendering sub-routes then specify the `*` wildcard at the end of of the "quoteId" route to allow further/more deeply matching.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='/quotes' />} />
        <Route path='/quotes' element={<AllQuotes />} />
        <Route path='/quotes/:quoteId/*' element={<QuoteDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also use relative matching/linking from the `QuoteDetail`, it's actually not necessary to know the current `quoteId` to create links to, and match, further sub-routes. You can just specify the relative path from the current location. Paths starting with `"/"` are absolute, and without are relative.

```
const QuoteDetail = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Quote Detail Page</h1>
      <p>{params.quoteId}</p>
      <Routes>
        <Route 
          path="comments"
          element={<p>Hello</p>}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit useparams-unable-to-fetch-path-dynamically-react-router-v6]

Comment: How can I render the quoteId dynamically on the QuoteDetail page?

Comment: @HITARTHVYAS Using `const params = useParams()` or `const { quoteId } = useParams()` should be sufficient enough for this. When the route changes and the url/path is different it should rerender the route, which rerenders the component. You should see any new `quoteId` match param values.

Comment: I tried to use `{ quoteId } = useParams()` and dynamically rendered the path in the route component but it didn't work actually as you can see my **QuoteDetails** code.

Comment: @HITARTHVYAS Do you see how it's working in my linked codesandbox? If it's still not working for you can you try creating your own codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Your codes are working sir but I don't know what is wrong with mine why is it showing `params.quoteId` undefined in `console.log()`

Comment: @HITARTHVYAS Are you seeing a log with the value undefined, and then another log with it defined? What if you logged the `quoteId` inside an `useEffect` hook as an ***intentional*** side-effect, i.e. *after* the component has mounted & rendered and the match param defined?

Comment: No, it was showing undefined every time. No, I haven't used `useEffect`, it was the same code that I asked as doubt. See `console.log()` below `params` in **QuoteDetails** code.

Comment: @HITARTHVYAS Is it undefined when rendering `<p>{params.quoteId}</p>`? I just don't see how `params` could possibly be entirely undefined unless the route and `QuoteDetail` are rendered *outside* a router, but at this point I'd expect to then see a bunch of warnings about not having a routing context. Did you also update the route paths as I did in my sandbox? Can you create a running codesandbox that repros the issue?

Comment: Your method is working fine sir but I want to ask that what is wrong with my method.

Comment: @HITARTHVYAS Dunno, my `QuoteDetail` component is a near copy/paste of yours, so I was suspecting it was something more to do with the router/route definition.

Comment: I guess sir, it might be due to this new version of react-router-dom library.

Comment: @HITARTHVYAS You are sure you're using `react-router-dom` version 6? From your project directory run `npm list react-router-dom`. The `useParams` hook didn't change from v5 to v6 though, but we can at least rule out version differences if necessary.